# No variants of io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.33.1 match the consumer attributes

Tags: java, android, gradle, dexguard, hyperledger-iroha

**Issue:**

I'm using `Dexguard` to obfuscate codes for `release` build.
Previously, I could build as normal without errors.
However, when I add this dependency `com.github.hyperledger:iroha-java:7.0.0`, the release build process failed with an error in the screenshot below:

[image]

I guess the library internally depends on `io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java`, but somehow Dexguard SDK can't find the dependency with the correct `artifactType = dexguard-consumer-rules`.

**What I have tried:**

- adding `io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.33.1`
- downgrading/upgrading version of `iroha-java`

Now I am not sure if the problem is caused by `Dexguard` or the `iroha-java` library.
So in case you have experiences related to this issue, please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone also faced this error:
The solution is to downgrade iroha version to 5.2.1 and exclude io.grpc from it.

```
implementation('com.github.hyperledger.iroha-java:client:5.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'protoc-gen-grpc-java'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dexguard can be causing the issue. In our experience it might be beneficial to just set up some rules within it so it would avoid the library. That should work.